# При открытии ссылки открывать фрагмент в APP

Tags: java, android

Всем привет! допустим есть ссылка https://example.com. Нужно чтобы при открытии этой ссылки в браузере открывался фрагмент ну или активити внутри приложения. Как например ютуб, когда открываешь https://www.youtube.com/ открывается их приложение. Как реализовать данный метод? Я читал данную документацию, но у меня ничего не получилось https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#java Если не сложно приведите подробный пример. Спасибо!

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com" />
            <data android:scheme="app" android:host="open.my.app" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: для начала объясните что именно у вас не получилось? предоставьте код вашей активити из манифеста, возможно вы неправильно составили intent-filter

Comment: @Tiarait добавил код

Comment: тестировал на 9 андроиде - все работает. при клике на ссылку (не вводе) предлагает открыть через хром или тестовое приложение

Comment: ааа, а я вводил ссылку и ничего не происходило:D А не знаете как сделать при вводе?

Comment: насколько я осведомлен - это невозможно https://stackoverflow.com/a/37089686/7540461